# Runtime c++ "undefined symbol" exception

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, undefined-symbol

I am getting an undefined symbol exception for a method that is actually executing.  This makes no sense to me.  Here is an example of the log:

/src/CustomerReturnProcessUtils/labelPrintUtils/CreturnLabelPrinter.cpp:402 (null)(): CreturnLabelPrinter: [InitializeZebraPrint] Success connecting to socket 
/apollo/env/CustomerReturnUIServiceUS/bin/CustomerReturnUIService: symbol lookup error: /apollo/env/CustomerReturnUIServiceUS/bin/CustomerReturnUIService: undefined symbol: _ZN19CreturnLabelPrinter10PrintLabelESsSsiiiSsbSs

The "Success connecting to socket" is logged by a method call INSIDE of CreturnLabelPrinter::PrintLabel...how can I be getting an undefined symbol exception for that?  This is a non-static method.  The code for it is not relevant (and I can't post it here anyways)...I am just wondering what conditions this could happen under.  I haven't seen any problems during the compiling and linking of these modules.  The calling method is in a different library than the "undefined symbol".

Comment: Have you looked at the code at line 402 of `CreturnLabelPrinter.cpp` to see what it's doing? At least as I read it, the symbol that's undefined is `ZN19CreturnLabelPrinter10PrintLabelESsSsiiiSsbSs` (which looks rather like a mangled name, so it might be something like `CReturnLablePrinter::PrintLabel` (or, quite possibly, something even more complex, but you get the general idea).

Answer (score 1):

Thi happened to me when I had 2 versions of the library and I was linking against the wrong one. Also c++filt shows:

```sh
$ c++filt __ZN19CreturnLabelPrinter10PrintLabelESsSsiiiSsbSs
CreturnLabelPrinter::PrintLabel(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
```

This has a huge list of arguments, did you check them?

Comment: I don't think it's a library version problem - this is a completely new source file I've added to the library, so it wouldn't work at all if I was using the wrong version.  I'll double check arguments though.

Comment: I had a new source file as well (an application actually), and it was linked against the library that was compiled with the debug flags. So the compilation of the app went through, and the execution failed in the same way you described..